# Using "since" in past and future perfect tense

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

As we usually say in **present tense:**

> It has been twenty days **since** I met you last.

In **past tense:**

> It had been twenty days **since** I **met** / **had met** you last.

Which tense should be used in the **subordinate clause?**

Now in **future tense:**

> It will have been twenty days **since** I **meet / met** you last.

The **present** is okay but please explain the **past** and the **future.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I'm not sure, I'm posting this as a comment. Correct me if I'm wrong, but *meet* in your third phrase is infinitive, not present, right? Also, I believe the correct tense would be future perfect too, since you're saying that 20 days will have elapsed since you did something *in the future* (if what I said is wrong, let me know and I'll delete this).

Answer (score 3):

The correct word is "met" in relation to your question.

"It will have been twenty days since I met her."
"It will have been twenty days since I met you."

It is also worth adding a few other points.

1. The "last" would normally be in the middle of the sentence, not at the end.
2. When referring to meeting you, as opposed to meeting a third party, it would usually be better to use "we.

The following examples illustrate two points above.

> "It has been twenty days since I met you last."

The above sounds clunky.

> "It will have been twenty days since I last met you."

The above option is good.

> "It will have been twenty days since we last met."

This third option is better.

> "It will have been twenty days since we met [to discuss the proposal]."

This fourth option is also good.

Finally, in relation to future events, "meet" is correct.

> "It will be twenty days until I meet her again.

"
Or ..

> "It will be twenty days until we meet again."

Comment: You didn't touch upon the "past"

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't understand the comment.  Could you please explain more fully?

Comment: What about my "second sentence"? What tense should I use after the word "since"-- past simple or past perfect?

Comment: "It had been twenty days since I had last met her" is the correct phrase.  ""It had been twenty days since I had last met you " is also correct, but it is a very strange construction; it might be used (for instance) if someone is writing a letter to the second person, explaining why they are breaking up with that person.  For instance, "It had been twenty days since I had last met you, but you did not want to hold my hand or hear about what I had been doing."

Comment: @EWalker a tiny little nitpicky detail here:  your future example is definitely correct for the more common case where the 'meeting' happened sometime in the past but the 'end of 20 days' will happen sometime in the future.  But what about the case where BOTH the 'meeting' and the '20 days' are in the future?  I believe in that case you'd have to use the future perfect on both sides of the word 'since'.  Like, "It will have been 20 days since we will last have met."  Of course that's a pretty niche case and I can't really imagine it actually being used in conversation!